# intellij can't dock variables tab in debug view

Tags: intellij-idea

I've somehow managed to undock the variables tab in the Debug view - so it's now a free floating window.

Must be missing something obvious but I can't see how to re-dock...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

On the left of the debug window is a column of icons:

[image: Debug Panel Icons]

The third one from the bottom resets all the panels.

Comment: No gear icon in the floating variables window.  That's what I would have expected but it's not there.